# XML Parsing app shows force close in real device

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have built a small application in android.I have used XML pull parser to retrieve the data from an xml file using a url.The problem is that when i test the app on emulator it works fine but when i test it on a real device it shows that the application has been stopped unexpectedly.Force close.What could be the reason for this?Please help me.

```
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.setInput(KXmlParser.java:1615)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at com.example.androidsample4.UNIXclass.getEventsFromAnXML(UNIXclass.java:84)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at com.example.androidsample4.UNIXclass$1.onClick(UNIXclass.java:54)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3131)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:12035)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
08-20 16:07:30.070 E/AndroidRuntime(10349): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 16:07:30.080 W/ActivityManager( 2900):   Force finishing activity com.example.androidsample4/.UNIXclass
```

Getting this in logcat

```
package com.example.androidsample4;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UNIXclass extends Activity 
{
    String unixcommands[];

    AutoCompleteTextView actv1;
    static final String URL="http://cympac.com/apps/xmlfile.xml";
    static final String KEY_COMMAND = "command"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_WORD = "word";
    static final String KEY_EXPLANATION = "explanation";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        AutoCompleteTextView actv=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        unixcommands=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Commands);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,unixcommands);
        actv1 = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        actv1.setThreshold(1);
        actv1.setAdapter(adapter);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                TextView myXmlContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                String stringXmlContent = null;
                try {
                    stringXmlContent = getEventsFromAnXML(getBaseContext());   //   54 line
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error:"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "error:"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                myXmlContent.setText(stringXmlContent);

            }
        });
    }









    public String getEventsFromAnXML(Context baseContext) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
    {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();

        java.net.URL url=new java.net.URL("http://cympac.com/apps/xmlfile.xml");
        XmlPullParserFactory factory=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp=factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url),"UTF_8");         //84 line
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        String word = null;

        String tag;
        while ((eventType = xpp.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {
            if(XmlPullParser.START_TAG==eventType)
            {
                tag=xpp.getName();
                //stringBuffer.append("\n"+tag);
                if (tag.equals("word"))
                {
                    eventType = xpp.next();
                    word = xpp.getText();
                }
                else if (tag.equals("explanation"))
                {
                    eventType = xpp.next();
                   //if ("cancel".equals(word))
                    if(actv1.getText().toString().equals(word))

                    {
                        stringBuffer.append("\n" + xpp.getText());
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();



    }
```

this is my code.I am getting IllegalArgument Exception

```
    public InputStream getInputStream(java.net.URL url2) 
    {

        try
        {
            return url2.openConnection().getInputStream();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not showing error in logcat

Comment: Then you'll probably need to add the catch-block and log the Exception manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are providing an illegal argument when supplying the parser with your XML data. According to the source you pass a null value.

See this thread: [Execute "doInBackground()" showing IllegalArgumentException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170151/execute-doinbackground-showing-illegalargumentexception)

Show us the line where you pass the XML to the KXmlParser.setInput method.

**Edit:** Your `getInputStream()` is returning null, and therefor the parser throws an IllegalArgumentException. Log the value of url2 before you use it, to see if it is null. You could also try to directly pass the stream as stated as the solution by the other question.

`xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");`

To

`xpp.setInput(url.openConnection().getInputStream(), "UTF_8");`

Answer (score 0):

if it only crashes on your device it would be helpfull to put the exception message in a string value and show it in an alert.

I had the same problem and it helped me to get an idea whats going wrong on the device.